# Multiple delete in two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Table `APP`

```
counter | Item
100001  | Ballpen  
100002  | Pencil  
100003  | Bond Paper  
100004  | Marker
```

Table `Purchase_Order`

```
counter | Status
100001  | Yes  
100001  | Yes  
100001  | Yes  
100004  | No
```

I want to delete all of counter 100001 in `app` and `purchase_order` tables. How can I do that?

And this is my code

app.php

```
<a href="app.php?de='.$row["counter"].'">

if(isset($_GET['de']))
{
$del_id=$_GET['de'];

sql= ...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general approach query would look like this

```sql
DELETE a, p
  FROM 
(
  SELECT 100001 counter
) q LEFT JOIN app a 
    ON q.counter = a.counter LEFT JOIN purchase_order p
    ON q.counter = p.counter;
```

It will delete rows in both tables even if one of them doesn't have rows with `counter = 100001`

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e114/1)** demo

Comment: yes it help. But I'm confuse on SELECT 100001 counter, can you gave a link or a tutorial to maximize my skills in SQL?

Comment: @altairelastname Great! I'm glad it helped. Actually it's a very simple concept, you don't need a tutorial for this. MySQL lacks `FULL JOIN` therefore to ensure that the leftmost (since we using `LEFT JOIN`) table has a row with a needed value we just create it on the fly with a simple select wrapped into a subquery. And then left join two actual tables to it.

Comment: Would you mine to check my newly question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944345/if-it-possible-to-changed-multiple-rows-value-using-checkbox bcoz I think you can answer it. Please

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
DELETE a.*, p.*
FROM app a
LEFT JOIN purchase_order p
    ON p.counter = a.counter
WHERE a.counter = 100001
```

Comment: Good thinking! One drawback though is that it won't work if `app` doesn't contain any rows with `counter = 100001`

Comment: I don't know why, but the counter in purchase_order not deleting.

Comment: @peterm If `app` doesn't have an entry, I don't think there'd be any log of `purchase_order`s.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
sql= "DELETE FROM a.*, b.* from app a LEFT JOIN purchase_order b 
on a.counter=b.counter where a.counter=".$del_id;
```

Comment: DELETE FROM a.*, b.* from ?

Comment: from "app" table. it will join the tables ("app" as a & "purchase_order" as b) and delete all those records with matching counter number

Comment: does not working. I used DELETE a.*, p.* FROM app a and it works. How this works a.counter=".$del_id? What is the use of ". ?

Comment: can you explain what didn't work? to answer your question-" a "." (dot" concatenates two strings in php.

Comment: if you're using my answer, then "p" is nowhere and it should not work. I clearly have aliased "app" as "a" and "puchase_order" as "b" in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below query

`DELETE a.*,b.* FROM app as a
LEFT JOIN purchase_order as b
ON a.counter=b.counter
WHERE a.counter=100001`