# If it possible to changed multiple rows value using checkbox?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

If it possible to edit my status field in my database when I check the checkbox?

What I want is, when I check multiple rows in my table it updates automatically the value of row['status'] in the database into yes after I submit.

Just like this,

Table APP

```
counter | status

100001  | 
100002  | 
100003  |   
100004  |
```

And when I checked the 100001 and 100002 the value of status changed to yes.

```
counter | status

100001  | yes
100002  | yes
100003  |   
100004  |
```

Below is my short code below.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");
$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM APP");
echo'<table id="tfhover">
<tr>
<th>status</th>
<th></th>
</tr>';
while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
echo
'<tr>
<td>'.$row['status'].'</td>
<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="'.$row['counter'].'"></td>
</tr></table>';
?>
<input id='edit' type='submit' class='button' name='edit' value='Edit'/> 
</form>

<?
if(isset($_POST['edit'])) 
{

}
?>
```

If it is possible to do this? Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you can try this code
at php

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['edit'])) 
{
     if(is_array($_POST['checkbox'])){
         $status = "yes";
         foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $key=>$value){
             $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE APP SET status=? WHERE counter= ?");
             $stmt->bind_param('ss', $status, $value);
             $stmt->execute();             
         }
     }else{
         echo "No changes";
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not use foreach?  This also doesn't validate the user input, so it could be susceptible to SQL injections.

Comment: @Hans: You should use foreach for arrays, it doesn't make sense to make a counter yourself.  Also you don't need `$checked_counter`, you could just do the count on `$_POST['checkbox']` with how you are using it.  @OP:  I suggest you sanitize user input so this code does not present security risks.  As it stands right now, someone could submit an SQL injection and delete your whole database.  You should also learn the basics and not be copy pasting, that way you understand what the code is doing.

Comment: @Devon if that so, would you mine to help me using for each?

Comment: I added an edit about 45 minutes ago with how the foreach should look.  It would have to be reviewed.  It looks like Hans added the validation to protect from SQL injections.  I still think you need to look into foreach and learning it yourself.  But foreach would be smaller code and almost always, smaller code = faster and better.

Comment: $devon, @altaire lastname : i have doing revision using foreach and prevent sql injection..

Comment: @Hans, I edited some errors I saw.  You should look into what I added.

Comment: @devon : already approve.. sorry new at SO,, so still slow in review the reviseon.. hehhee, btw why need you $key=> ??, isn't that if $key=>$value and only $value will be same result

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.  I believe when the $_POST["checkbox"] is viewed (you can test this with `print_r($_POST['checkbox']);`) you will see that it will be:  `array( [0] => 100001, [1] = 100002 )` and so on.  So the $key would be 0, the $value would be 100001.  The value is what you want.  If you just had a single level array where the keys were [100001], [100002] then you wouldn't need the key=>

Answer (score 0):

The `name="checkbox[]"` will create an array in $_POST["checkbox"] for you to use.  The array will contain the values of all the checkboxes you selected.

Comment: and How can I do that?

Comment: Well I won't write the code for you.  But the easiest way to analyze all the values of an array is using http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php